# Link checker modules fails to detect a test broken link

Tags: 7

I downloaded, installed, enabled and configured the linkchecker module.  When I run it from the Drupal interface, it seems to be checking but I don't see in the report a test link (within ) that I have purposefully misspelled. This test link is to an external site.  Does it matter for the link checker module if my development site is not publicly accessible-- I think it is accessible only from campus.

Linkchecker version 6.x-2.7; drupal-6.26

Answer (score 0):

### Found Link checker works after  'run cron'

-- Found in video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hcl9iwIFZ2k
That a cron job has to be run after the configuring.
--  I had already set for automatic running of cron job.  For some reason it didn't work.
--  It worked after running cron job manually.
`site-url/cron.php` for D5 and D6

-- OR For Drupal 6.x, see in your site: Administer > Reports > Status report > Cron maintenance tasks > Run cron manually.

#### Steps for checking links:

1. Make sure link checker configuration is what you want
2. `http://site-url/cron.php`  in browser to run cron job (it yields blank page after the run)
3. See report for broken links and follow up specific links.

Here is another link for some relevant info on link checker module:
http://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/module-monday-link-checker